# How to use predefined Strings inside Room Database query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Is it possible to use predefined Strings inside the Room Query? For instance:

```
@Query("delete from Bookmarks where listName != Constants.SOME_LIST_NAME")
void deleteAllBookmarks();
```

Just to be clear, I don't want to pass it as a parameter:

```
@Query("delete from Bookmarks where listName != :listName")
void deleteAllBookmarks(String listName);
```

and I don't want to hardcode it (it is used in more than one place):

```
@Query("delete from Bookmarks where listName != 'MyList'")
void deleteAllBookmarks();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if that's supported, someone can probably prove me wrong but until then... you know...

Assuming that `SOME_LIST_NAME = "MyList"` then you could just do:

```
@Query("delete from Bookmarks where listName != MyList")
void deleteAllBookmarks();
```

Comment: By _" And I don't want to hardcode it (it is used in more than one place)"_ I meant that I don't want to do it the way you wrote. As I use that list name in more than one place, I don't want to copy that hardcoded "MyList" everywhere.

Comment: I understand that it's not what you want, but assuming that you don't have it in *that* many places, spending even an hour on this is pretty wasted imo. But hopefully someone can come in here and prove that it's possible. :)

Comment: It just doesn't look clean that way. It is error-prone and in case if you decide to change the list name you have to change it everywhere. Thank you for your suggestion anyway :)